# Multiple images in a rails image tag

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I'd like to know if it's possible to pass an array to a rails image tag. The array would include a series of png images and I'd like for the view to display those images on rotation.

Does anyone know how to do that?

This does not work.

```
<div class="img-circle"><%= image_tag ["researcher.png", "book.png"], size: "150x150" %></div>
```

I can't seem to find instructions (the rails guides suggest that you can pass an array to the video tag helper so I was wondering if there were a way to do the same thing with images).

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extend @Rich Peck's answer, what about creating a helper to do that, it's cleaner I think :

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def images_tag(array_of_images, options={})
    images = []
    if array_of_images.is_a? Array
      array_of_images.each do |image|
        images << image_tag(image, size: options[:size], class: options[:class])
      end
    end
    content_tag :div, images.join("\n").html_safe, class: "img-circle"
  end
end
```

then, in your view :

```
<%= images_tag ["researcher.png", "book.png"], size: "150x150", class: "class-img" %>
```

will output :

```
<div class="img-circle">
  <img alt="researcher" class="class-img" height="150" src="/assets/researcher.png" width="150">
  <img alt="book" class="class-img" height="150" src="/assets/book.png" width="150">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for this - I'm getting this error message when I try to implement this. I haven't used helpers before so not sure if I'm making a basic error
    Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant EquationHelper

Comment: Well, you should place this code inside your `application_helper.rb` file. Let me refactor my example. Also, which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your help. I'm still getting the same error (circular dependency). I'm using rails 4.

Comment: About your error, be sure `EquationHelper` is matching the file name, for example `equation_helper.rb`

Comment: I just moved the helper code to the application helper. I have a view called _equation.html.erb

Comment: hi again, the circular error has been resolved but the effect of this code is that the images appear alongside each other. I was hoping for a single image container and a series of images inside of it. I might try a carousel.js to achieve that effect. Any other ideas. Thank you very much again.

Comment: Hi, you can modify the helper to match your needs. If you show me the HTML code you want to output, I could help you to modify it to work the way you want. Cheers

Comment: Hi El Key, I'm not sure what the best way to go about the html is. I'd like to have a single image holder which has a number of images cycling through it in the view. the html is just a placeholder for the image - with no styling.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting - I think you're only able to use one image per `image_tag` currently

As you can see from [the API](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag), the method is a way to post the `<img src="">` HTML tag, and I believe that it only does this once (does not replicate for multiple images)

A way to achieve what you want would be to use a loop, although it's kind of bloated for what you're looking for here:

```
<% images = %w(reearcher.png book.png) %>
<% for image in images do %>
    <%= image_tag image, size: "150x150" %>
<% end %>
```