# How to insert images instead of certain letters in a word?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

[From my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39820430/how-to-transform-a-user-input-in-rails-4)I am creating an app where users could enter their name that will be returned as chemical symbols (when matching).

I want to use **real symbols** as images, I tried with the breaking bad fonts but I don't like the result...
So I have to display images as the values of my hash...
Here's a little sample of the symbols

```
class Convertor < ActiveRecord::Base

  def get_chemical
    symbols = {
      "ac" => "symbols/ac.jpg",
      "al" => "symbols/al.jpg",
      "am" => "symbols/am.jpg",
      "br" => "symbols/br.jpg",
      "ba" => "symbols/ba.jpg",
      "cr" => "symbols/cr.jpg"
      #there are soooo many I have to make sure how to do before creating all the keys, values

   }
    name.downcase.gsub!(Regexp.union(symbols.keys), symbols)
  end
end
```

**The main problem is that I can't figure how to do a loop around what is a chemical symbol and what isn't, because I will have several pictures in a row that represent the chemical symbols or the none chemical letters... And now only one is displayed...**

this is the views/show

```
 = image_tag(@convertor.get_chemical)
```

For now in my app/assets/images I onlyhave two testing images br.jpg and al.jpg

If in my form I ask for "br" conversion I have:

[image]

If I ask for "bral" conversion I have :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*image_tag* uses a single image file as a source, I suggest making *get_chemical* return an array of file URLs, which you can pass to a function as described in this answer: [Multiple images in a rails image tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23308565/6275230)